# Why the android runtime permission dialogs not handled by google(eg - play services - location) libraries in default?

Tags: android, android-permissions

While migrating to run time permission model, I've a doubt . Why google play services libraries not handling the run time permissions? they can ask run time permissions from library itself right?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because it's part of the user interaction. There's more than just asking for permissions, you also need to properly handle the case when the permission is denied and when it's asked again, providing a reasoning to the user why you keep bugging about the permission. Also Google wants you to be aware of when the permission is asked, doing that without your explicit control could take the developer and the user by surprise.

Also: You can't ask for the permission without declaring it in the manifest. If you don't ask for the permission yourself you might not remember to add it.

Comment: yes. More control for the developer & the user. Less responsibility for google. Everybody wins

Answer (score 0):

The concern is **Security.** They don't know what you have planned to do with the permissions but the user knows (assumed) the consequences allowing you for a permission. So user is solely responsible for any damage due to usages of an application. In other words Google is out of damage-scene.